# Extract data from javascript object & translate some symbols

Tags: javascript

I'm iterating over a javascript object to get some saved data. 
I tested isolated sections in this function and they are working as 
expected. The thing is that my function tries to present the 'modified'
data to another function("`drawBricks()`" ) to use.

For simplicity, here are the functions:

```
//DrawBricks function
function drawBricks() {
  for(c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for (r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
      if(bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
        var brickX = (c*(brickWidth+brickPadding))+brickOffsetLeft;
        var brickY = (r*(brickHeight+brickPadding))+brickOffsetTop;
        bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
        bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      }
    }
  }
}

//ActiveLevel()
function activeLevel(){
 var checkLevel;
 var stringLvl
 var levelArray = ['r1','r2','r3'];
 var blocks = [];
 for(i=0; i<=gems.length; i++) {
    if(level == gems[i].id){
        checkLevel = gems[i];           
    }
 }
 levelArray.forEach(function (k) {
    stringLvl = checkLevel.row[k];
    stringLvl = stringLvl.split('');
 });
 for(c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++){
    blocks[c] = [];
    blocks.push(stringLvl[c]);
    for(r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++){
        blocks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0, status: 1 };
        blocks.push(stringLvl[c][r]);
        if(blocks[c][r] == "-"){
            status = 0;
        }
        else if(blocks[c][r] == "*"){
            status = 1;
        }
        bricks = blocks;
    }
 }
 // drawBricks();
}
```

Here is the object that I use

```
  var gems = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Level-1',
    row: {
      r1: '*****',
      r2: '-***-',
      r3: '--*--'
    },
    canPushtoDb: true,
    hideLevel: false,
    status: 1
    //Other gems with corresponding id and name values, havent 
    //added them here to reduce the length of the question
  }
```

I think the problem is that while I'm still using `drawBrick`, it is not reading
the data properly from `activeLevel()`. So, what you think about `activeLevel()`?

Comment: you are setting a lot of global variants, don't do it, if a function need some info, pass it as an argument `drawBricks(bricks)`. you will be really confused in few days when you will get back to that code, and will try to upgrade it, this will also save you the trouble to find where your error is, because now it can be anywhere on the page.

Comment: well, that's a good observation, thanks, i will. I'm just hard-codding for testing. I expect to refactor the whole thing, in some advanced state of their own, But thanks any way it's a good point!

Comment: have you tried to console log the variants to see what they hold in drawbrick? what exactly the problem is? what is not working ?

Comment: I linking variables on elements out of canvas instead. And all test present the same problem: anything is drawing on canvas, so this means the function is not ending properly, and because i must calling it before any other function, that answer some question -> the function fall in a loop and their 'work' is not reached from the next function `drawBricks()`. I think!!!

Comment: Yes, yes, i tested both. after calling `activeLevel` -> canvas blocked.  And without calling it -> it shows the expected array pushed from their `for` loop.

Comment: If you had error this would show in the console, and you would see what is really not working, if you don't have errors in the console, that means that everything is working like it should, but the data you sending or getting is not right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129524/discussion-between-yan-mayatskiy-and-hell0).

Comment: I refactored the code, adopting `ruby` syntax(beter to understand i think). Now the problem is to rise the source from `gems` array, and how the machine is reading and in fact drawing the __real__ array i'm working on. Here is the link http://kopy.io/CuT7d

Comment: join the chat..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that problem was solved like this:

```
function activeLevel(){
    var checkLevel;                     // Actual level.
    var levelArray = ['r1','r2','r3'];  // string inside object.row.
    var stringLvl = []; 


  gems.forEach(function(value, i) {
    if(gems[i].id == level){
      checkLevel = gems[i].row;
    }
  });

  //console.log("step 1 - checkLevel is:", checkLevel);

  levelArray.forEach(function (value, i) {    
    stringLvl[i] = checkLevel[value].split(''); 
    });

  //console.log("step 2 - stringLvl is:", stringLvl);  

  stringLvl.forEach(function(c, r) {    
    stringLvl[r].forEach(function(value, index) {      
      if(stringLvl[r][index] == "-") {        
        bricks[index][r].status = 0;
      }
      else {        
        bricks[index][r].status = 1;
      }
    });
  });  
  // console.log("step 3 - blocks is:", blocks);
  drawBricks();

}
```

I still thinking in C/C++, but adopting *Ruby* syntax, the source gain on readability and it is much more elegant.